# SearchDialog cannot be shown within ActivityGroup

Tags: android, activitygroup

i have two activities within an ActivityGroup, one "ProvinceActivity" and another "CityActivity".
so code:

```
public class CityManagerActivity extends ActivityGroup {
    View v1 = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(
                "tab1",
                new Intent(this, ProvinceActivity.class)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                .getDecorView();
    replaceView(v1);
}
```

but when  I have a default searchable  by pressing search-key  in the "tab1" the search i have the ERROR:

```
08-19 17:18:23.438: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9078): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception 
08-19 17:18:23.458: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9078): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no ident 
08-19 17:18:23.458: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9078):     at android.app.Activity.ensureSearchManager(Activity.java:3499) 
08-19 17:18:23.458: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9078):     at android.app.Activity.startSearch(Activity.java:2648) 
08-19 17:18:23.458: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9078):     at android.app.Activity.onSearchRequested(Activity.java:2612) ...
```

the second search works,tell me how to do it,plz...

Comment: I had resolve this problem,i overried the method in ProvinceActivity:
 public boolean onSearchRequested() {
  return CityManagerActivity.group.onSearchRequested();
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have same problem. I use this and it fix the problem.

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For others i think by just returning true the app shows an behavior which the user does not expect because it should show some kind of search and by returning true this is overridden.

The article http://www.app-solut.com/blog/2011/10/unexpected-behavior-when-working-with-nested-tabhosts/ shows a good way how to solve this problem in a TabHost without changing the default behavior.